# Issue with connection to snowflake using c# console application running on EC2

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a C# console application which is using Snowflake .NET connector to connect with Snowflake DB. Application is working fine on my system however if I take that application to EC2 and execute then it's not connecting to Showflake DB with giving error "SnowflakeDbException: Request reach its timeout".

Network connectivity between AWS EC2 instance and Snowflake DB is in place.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IDbConnection conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = "scheme=https;account=<accountname>;port=443;user=. 
               <xxxxxx>;password=<xxxxxx>;ROLE=<definedRole>;warehouse=<warehouse>;db=
                <DBNAME>;schema=<schemaname>";

                conn.Open();  //ERROR: "SnowflakeDbException: Request reach its timeout"

                Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");
                using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from TABLE1";  
                    //data from an existing table
                    IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DbException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Message: {0}", exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

If I do 'Test-NetConnection' command using powershell as below then it is succeeded.

```
Test-NetConnection -computerName xxxx.eu-west-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com -port 443
```

Result: TCPTestSucceeded : True

[StackTrace Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etnG8.jpg)

[Trace post enabling Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZRPK.png)

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed:
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

[cURL output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JMnr.png)

[SnowCD output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GcDh.png)

Comment: What is this "sheme=https" ?

Comment: 1. Do you have logging enabled? The log should show a bit more information about the issue. 2. Are you able to run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) on that EC2?

Comment: @Sergiu, I have attached text file for the tracing post enabling logging.

Comment: Do you have *cURL* installed (can be installed from [cURL](https://curl.se/windows/))?  If yes, what do you get when you run this on the command line: *curl -v -X POST xxxx.eu-west-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com* ? The log provided just shows that you're not able to establish a connection within the 2 min timeout period.

Comment: @sergiu, I have updated 'connection_timeout' in connection string to 300. Now, it gives more detail error. Please refer updated Trace

Comment: @sameerA Do you have a proxy in between? It looks like the SSL handshake is failing. This is where SnowCD output I mentioned before would help.

Comment: @sergiu,  I also attached output of cURL by running  command 
curl -v -X POST xxxx.eu-west-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com

Thanks for your inputs..

Comment: @sameerA You're failing the [CRL check](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ocsp.html). Try setting parameter *INSECUREMODE=true* to disable certificate revocation list check, but in a production system this is not recommended, just for your test now.

Comment: @sergiu, Also, attaching output for SnowCD. Thanks

Comment: @sameerA SnowCD also confirms you're failing CRL check. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @sergiu,
Post setting 'INSECUREMODE=true', source code worked on EC2. I will got through OCSP Configuration to make appropriate changes to support it in Production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are failing the [CRL check](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ocsp.html). Setting the parameter **INSECUREMODE=true** will disable the certificate revocation list check and test should pass, but this is not recommended in a production system.